# modify 3d column of 335 random lines with bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with more than 3000 lines and 3 columns. For the moment, the third column contains just a "0" in each line. I would like to randomly select 335 lines and change the "0" in the third column by a "1" (in the same file, if possible).

I've tried something with `shuf` but it's not working:

```
shuf -n 335 myfile.txt | awk -d'\t' '$3==1'
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does the order of lines otherwise matter?

Comment: No, not at all!

Comment: Where do you have `awk -d` from?

Comment: In what way is it `not working`? No output, wrong output, core dump, error messages, summoning Cthulhu, something else? [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output (we do NOT need to see a 3000 line example - 5 lines that you select 3 of at random would demonstrate the issue just fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of lines doesn't matter at all, as you say in comments, you can use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR<336{$3=1}1' test.txt | shuf
```

Comment: You should be calling `shuf | awk`, not `awk | shuf`. As written it'll always print the first 335 lines rather than selecting 335 lines at random from 3000.

Comment: Hi! Why do you think that? The result would be a file where the `1`s aren't randomly distributed but all at the beginning of the file

Comment: The 1s won't be randomly distributed in the output but they will be randomly distributed across **input** lines. You can tack on an additional `shuf` if that's useful. I actually thought the OP ONLY wanted a random 335 of the input lines output or wanted the input order preserved but a random 335 lines of it modified. I can't imagine her wanting to always change the first 335 lines and THEN shuffle them but idk - I've asked for a [mcve] in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you really want:

```
cat -n file | shuf | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR<=355{$3=1} 1' | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2-
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat -n file | shuf | awk 'NR<=2{$0=$0 " modified"} 1' | sort -k1,1n | cut -f2-
1
2
3 modified
4
5 modified
```

The above is changing 2 of the 5 input lines and outputting all the lines in the original order.